# fieldASTs on GraphQL resolve

Tags: graphql

I have been going crazy over this for GraphQL. I have seen a lot of resources referring to this last fieldASTs param for the selectionSet. However, it doesn't seem to be there. I haven't found any solid evidence that it is, but it has been brought up in github issues and tutorials. I am a little confused by this. Is there or is there not a 4th param?

I have also tested the other params to see if I can pull it off of those.

```
 const SomeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
     name: 'SomeObject',
     fields: () => ({
         someItems : {
         type: new GraphQLList(SomeCustomType),
         resolve: (someItems, params, source, fieldASTs) => {
             const projections = getProjection(fieldASTs);
             return SomeModel.find({}, projections);
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

with current version (0.7.0), now it is in the forth argument, third argument is for context.

the following observation from this blog post may help.
http://pcarion.com/2015/09/27/GraphQLResolveInfo/

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I found it. I dove through the changelogs and it was changed to be part of the third param. However, it isn't structured the same way

```
resolve: (item, params, info, fieldASTs) => {
  //used to be
  fieldASTs.selectionMap.selection.reduce(someLogic);

  //now its simply
  fieldASTs.reduce(someLogic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `graphql@0.4.14`, and found it here:

```
info //third argument
.fieldASTs[0]
.selectionSet
.selections
//.reduce...
```

I guess they are still changing everything, so I've added try/catch to `getProjection()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes the fourth param comprises of fieldASTs but its hooked under the object as an array

```
const SomeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
     name: 'SomeObject',
     fields: () => ({
         someItems : {
         type: new GraphQLList(SomeCustomType),
         resolve: (someItems, params, source, options) => {
             const projections = getProjection(options.fieldASTs[0]);
             return SomeModel.find({}, projections);
      }
    }
  });
```

This solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

In `express-graphql` being graphql v0.8.1 I had to do it like this (note the use of mongoose too):

```
function getProjection (fieldASTs) {
  return fieldASTs.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections.reduce((projections, selection) => {
    projections[selection.name.value] = 1;

    return projections;
  }, {});
}

resolve (root, params, info, fieldASTs) {

    let filter = {};

    if(params._id){
      filter._id = params._id;
    }

    var projections = getProjection(fieldASTs);
    return grocerModel.find(filter).select(projections).exec();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to graphql, but this resolved it for me and I think something may have changed in the versions as fieldASTs did not exist on the options (4th param) object, but fieldNodes does that has the necessary child objects to perform the projection.

```html
export default {
    type: new GraphQLList(teamType),
    args: {
        name: {
            type: GraphQLString
        }
    },
    resolve(someItems, params, source, options) {

        const projection = getProjection(options.fieldNodes[0])

        return TeamModel
            .find()
            .select(projection)
            .exec()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 competing Open Source libraries to achieve what topic starter was asking for:

- [graphql-fields-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-fields-list)
- [graphql-list-fields](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-list-fields)

They both try to solve the same problem, but the former seem to have some more features, including TypeScript support out of the box.